# Javascript - will a canceled request affect performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, xmlhttprequest

Our application is using angular and get a lot of requests. There is a group of request (Request BCD) has dependency on watching data returned by another request.(Please see attachment) So when first load the page, it will send BCD requests and A request was sent at same time. When A request returned data, BCD request will send again and the earlier BCD request will be abort(Canceled).

My question is: since the request was canceled anyway, will this affect my page loading time? Should I implement something like a promise to let BCD request wait for A request finish then watch data returned from A request?

[Screen shoot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAg7c.png)

Comment: In my understanding, cancelling a request should not have any impact as XHR is async

Comment: This is such a broad (and vague) question that your best answer is the one at your fingertips.  If you've been given reason to look at performance then measure it and see if there's a difference.  That's the easiest (and most relevant and correct) way to determine if there's any issue anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be additional work as engine will have to perform certain actions to cancel request. You can find steps [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20140130/#the-abort()-method)

As you see engine will have to fire following events:

- readystatechange
- progress
- abort
- loadend

Along with updating some flags. But these work will take very less time and delay in performance would be negligible.

---

**Edit 1:**

If you refer [concept-event-fire-progress](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire-progress), mentioned events will be fired anyways except `abort`. It would be `error` or `load` or `timeout` based on status. But cancelling a request would make engine fire these events right away and this might add some time. But again, the total time will be negligible.

Comment: Thank for your reply Rajesh! 
It feels same to me that it is negligible to fire a aborting request.
But this request will not be aborted until another request return. In this case I am shooting 4 requests, do you think it will take A LOT more time since 4 request are shooting than one request? 

(Plus, thanks again for replying, i am going to do this optimistic no matter it delay big time or small, but I am just interested to know is it taking similar time to shoot 1 request and more requests)

Comment: Yes making 4 request will take a bit more but than this is what you what. You can always look into web socket if you wish real time updates. Also you can look into `console.time` to match the performance. Remember, this will not have performance impact on your website, but it will have impact on server as its load will increase.